# I want to throw list of response in JSON like below

Tags: json

```
{
  "url": "https://na34.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/EMPYRAMDM/v1/sourceMDMServices",
  "status": null,
  "message": null
},
{
  "url": "https://na34.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/EMPYRAMDM/v1/sourceMDMServices",
  "status": null,
  "message": null
}
```

Rest Code

```
@RestResource(urlMapping = '/v1/sourceMDMServices/*')
global class sourceMDMServices{
@HttpGet
    global static messageWrapper getAccountWrapperDetail() {
    messageWrapper response=new messageWrapper ();
    response.url=https://na34.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/EMPYRAMDM/v1/sourceMDMServices,https://na34.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/EMPYRAMDM/v1/sourceMDMServices;
    return response;
    }
    global class messageWrapper {
        public list<String> status;
        public list<String> message;
        public list<String> url;


        public messageWrapper () {}
    }
}
```

I started like above,now I stuck,I am not getting how it achieve it,pls help.thanks in advance

Comment: where are you stuck? What is the problem? What doesn't work as excepted?

Answer (score 1):

What you need in your json is a list of objects, not an object of lists. So in your code:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping = '/v1/sourceMDMServices/*')
global class sourceMDMServices{
@HttpGet
    global static messageWrapper getAccountWrapperDetail() {
        List<messageWrapper> response =new List<messageWrapper>();
        messageWrapper wrapper = new messageWrapper();
        wrapper.url= 'https://na34.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/EMPYRAMDM/v1/sourceMDMServices,https://na34.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/EMPYRAMDM/v1/sourceMDMServices';
        response.add(wrapper);
        return response;
    }
    global class messageWrapper {
        public String status;
        public String message;
        public String url;

        public messageWrapper () {}
    }
}
```